# My Word VBA UserForm is not populating my template as expected, but does not produce an error message. Why?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The expected behavior when I click the OK button is populating the form with the information entered by the user. Instead, nothing happens. The document remains unchanged, but I don't receive an error message. Why is this happening?

It also doesn't interact very well with the Code Sample button, either. I'm not sure why, so apologies for the ugliness below. There's a Pastebin link http://pastebin.com/GmbVXAxk that looks a little prettier.

```
Public Function ValidateData() As Boolean

    ValidateData = True

    If txtName.Value = "" Then

        MsgBox "Please enter the candidate's name", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

    End If

    If cboProvince.Value = "" Then

        MsgBox "Please select a province", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

    End If

    If txtCity.Value = "" Then

        MsgBox "Please enter a city", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

    End If


    If txtStreetAddress.Value = "" Then

        MsgBox "Please enter a street address", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

    End If

    If txtPostalCode.Value = "" Then

        MsgBox "Please enter the candidate's postal code", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

    End If

    If txtPosition.Value = "" Then

        MsgBox "Please enter the candidate's position", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

    End If

    If txtStartDate.Value = "" Or Not IsDate(txtStartDate.Value) Then

        MsgBox "Please enter the candidate's start date", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

    End If

    If txtAnnualSalary = "" Or Not IsNumeric(txtAnnualSalary.Value) Then

        MsgBox "Please enter a total salary using numbers only", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

    End If


    If cboPaymentFrequency = "" Then

        MsgBox "Please select a payment frequency", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

    End If

    If txtTotalVacation = "" Or Not IsNumeric(txtTotalVacation.Value) Then

        MsgBox "Please enter the total number of vacation days", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

    End If

    If cboDepartment.Value = "" Then

        MsgBox "Please select the candidate's department", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

     End If

     If optRegards.Value = False And optSincerely.Value = False And optYoursTruly.Value = False And optBestWishes.Value = False Then

        MsgBox "Please selection a sign off", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

     End If

     If txtSignersName.Value = "" Then

        MsgBox "Please Enter the signer's name", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

     End If

    If txtSignersTitle.Value = "" Then

        MsgBox "Please Enter the signer's title", , "Missing Information"
        ValidateData = False
        Exit Function

     End If

End Function
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()

    frmEmploymentOffer.Hide
    Unload frmEmploymentOffer

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()

    txtName.Value = ""
    cboProvince.Value = ""
    txtCity.Value = ""
    txtStreetAddress.Value = ""
    txtPostalCode.Value = ""
    txtPosition.Value = ""
    txtStartDate.Value = ""
    txtAnnualSalary.Value = ""
    cboPaymentFrequency.Value = ""
    txtTotalVacation.Value = ""
    cboDepartment.Value = ""
    optRegards.Value = False
    optSincerely.Value = False
    optBestWishes.Value = False
    optYoursTruly.Value = False
    txtSignersName.Value = ""
    txtSignersTitle.Value = ""

End Sub
Private Sub PopulateTemplate()

'Takes input and transfers it to the form in the appropriate fields

    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Name").Range.Text = txtName.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Province").Range.Text = cboProvince.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("City").Range.Text = txtCity.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("StreetAddress").Range.Text = txtStreetAddress.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PostalCode").Range.Text = txtPostalCode.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Position").Range.Text = txtPosition.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("StartDate").Range.Text = txtStartDate.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("AnnualSalary").Range.Text = txtAnnualSalary.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PaymentFrequency").Range.Text = cboProvince.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TotalVacation").Range.Text = txtTotalVacation.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Department").Range.Text = cboDepartment.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SignersName").Range.Text = txtSignersName.Value
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SignersTitle").Range.Text = txtSignersTitle.Value

'Adds the correct sign off to the document

    If optBestWishes.Value = True Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ClosingGreeting").Range.Text = "Best Wishes"

    ElseIf optYoursTruly.Value = True Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ClosingGreeting").Range.Text = "Yours truly"

    ElseIf optSincerely.Value = True Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ClosingGreeting").Range.Text = "Sincerely"

    Else

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ClosingGreeting").Range.Text = "Regards"

    End If

'Calculates monthly vacation by dividing TotalVacation input by 12

    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MonthlyVacation").Range.Text = txtTotalVacation.Value / 12

'Calculates salary amount per pay period by dividing annual salary input by user by
'the number of weeks in that pay period

    If cboPaymentFrequency.Value = "Weekly" Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("EarningsPerPayPeriod").Range.Text = txtAnnualSalary.Value / 52

    ElseIf cboPaymentFrequency.Value = "Bi-Weekly" Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("EarningsPerPayPeriod").Range.Text = txtAnnualSalary.Value / 26

    ElseIf cboPaymentFrequency.Value = "Monthly" Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("EarningsPerPayPeriod").Range.Text = txtAnnualSalary.Value / 12

    ElseIf cboPaymentFrequency.Value = "Quarterly" Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("EarningsPerPayPeriod").Range.Text = txtAnnualSalary.Value / 4

    Else

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("EarningsPerPayPeriod").Range.Text = txtAnnualSalary

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

If ValidateData = False Then

    Exit Sub

End If

'Closes the form after information is entered
  frmEmploymentOffer.Hide
  Unload frmEmploymentOffer

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Province
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboProvince.AddItem "Alberta", 0
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboProvince.AddItem "British Columbia", 1
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboProvince.AddItem "Manitoba", 2
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboProvince.AddItem "New Brunswick", 3
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboProvince.AddItem "Newfoundland and Labrador", 4
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboProvince.AddItem "Northwest Territories", 5
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboProvince.AddItem "Nova Scotia", 6
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboProvince.AddItem "Nunavut", 7
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboProvince.AddItem "Ontario", 8
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboProvince.AddItem "Prince Edward Island", 9
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboProvince.AddItem "Quebec", 10
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboProvince.AddItem "Saskatchewan", 11
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboProvince.AddItem "Yukon Territory", 12

    'Payment Frequency
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboPaymentFrequency.AddItem "Weekly", 0
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboPaymentFrequency.AddItem "Bi-Weekly", 1
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboPaymentFrequency.AddItem "Monthly", 2
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboPaymentFrequency.AddItem "Quarterly", 3

    'Department
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboDepartment.AddItem "Administration", 0
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboDepartment.AddItem "Business Resource", 1
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboDepartment.AddItem "Finance", 2
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboDepartment.AddItem "Human Resources", 3
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboDepartment.AddItem "IT", 4
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboDepartment.AddItem "Legal", 5
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboDepartment.AddItem "Operations", 6
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboDepartment.AddItem "Sales", 7
    frmEmploymentOffer.cboDepartment.AddItem "Technology", 8

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add PopulateTemplate before hiding the userform

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

    If ValidateData = False Then

        Exit Sub

    End If

    PopulateTemplate

    'Closes the form after information is entered
    frmEmploymentOffer.Hide

End Sub
```